# ModuleNotFoundError: py3k for PyInstaller + savReaderWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, spss

I want to use PyInstaller with module savReaderWriter. My code is very simple:

```
import savReaderWriter

print("hello world")
input("Press enter, to finish...")
```

I was trying to use hidden import with appropriate module:

```
pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --upx-exclude=vcruntime140.dll --onedir --hidden-import="savReaderWriter" temp.py
```

```
pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --upx-exclude=vcruntime140.dll --onedir --hidden-import="py3k" temp.py
```

```
pyinstaller --clean --win-private-assemblies --upx-exclude=vcruntime140.dll --onedir --hidden-import="py3k" --hidden-import="savReaderWriter" temp.py
```

But in all cases I have received the same error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py3k'
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by including the path of the savReaderWriter to the parameter.

```
pyinstaller -p "C:\PyProjects\test\venv\Lib\site-packages\savReaderWriter"; test.py
```

Also, the real pain is when you trying to delete the module, an Error will occur because it is finding a non "UTF-8" character.